# filter by polygon draw in geodjango

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

Let's say user draw polygon and request to the backend for filtration. As I can filter by bounding box but Can geodjango queryset filter within the drawing area?

For instance, I have an object with data in the `multilinestring` field.

```
class Datasets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    multipoint = models.MultiPointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326)
    multilinestring = models.MultiLineStringField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
    multipoly = models.MultiPolygonField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326)
    objects = GeoManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

We should consider 2 possibilities for our data (`multilinestring`) in conjunction with the given (drawn) `Polygon`:

1. The `Polygon` [`intersects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#intersects) our data.

   Then the query should look like this:

   ```
   Datasets.objects.filter(multilinestring__intersects=Polygon)
   ```
2. The data are completely [`within`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within) the `Polygon`.

   Then the query should look like this:

   ```
   Datasets.objects.filter(multilinestring__within=Polygon)
   ```

We can even combine the 2 and search for data that are either `within` **or** `intersect` the given `Polygon`. To achieve that we can use Django's [`Q() object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and the `| (OR)` operator as follows:

```
Datasets.objects.filter(
    Q(multilinestring__intersects=Polygon) |
    Q(multilinestring__within=Polygon)
)
```

Comment: Hey, @saroj-rai I was making a pass over my answers and I was wondering, did you find this useful?