# django get polygons inside coordinates

Tags: django, gis, geodjango

I have a coordinate that the frontend gives me like

```
"[[{"lat":45.36324254131911,"lng":2.471923828125},{"lat":46.667815881216754,"lng":2.471923828125},{"lat":46.667815881216754,"lng":6.50390625},{"lat":45.36324254131911,"lng":6.50390625}]]"
```

This is a rectangle.

I have a model where I am storing Polygon data

```
from djgeojson.fields import PolygonField

class MyCords(models.Model):

    geom = PolygonField()
```

a single instance of Mycords.geom gives me data like:

```
{'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[5.328369, 45.251688],
   [5.910645, 44.980342],
   [6.328125, 45.375302],
   [6.075439, 45.859412],
   [5.471191, 45.698507],
   [5.328369, 45.251688]]]}
```

Here I want to filter all the MyCords that lie in the given coordinates.

How can I get this through queryset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires 2 steps:

1. Create a [`Polygon`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#polygon) from the input coordinates. We need to read through the list and create a list of coordinate tuples (as per the linked documentation):

   ```
   input_coords = json.loads("[[{"lat":45.36324254131911,"lng":2.471923828125},{"lat":46.667815881216754,"lng":2.471923828125},{"lat":46.667815881216754,"lng":6.50390625},{"lat":45.36324254131911,"lng":6.50390625}]]")
   coord_lst = [(pair['lat'], pair['lng']) for pair in input_coords]

   # Note: In order to have a valid Polygon, the first coord pair 
   # needs to be equal to the last pair:
   coord_lst.append(coord_lst[0])
   input_polygon = Polygon(coord_lst)
   ```

   *Note:* if the input is a bounding box and you know the `(Xmin, Ymin)` and `(Xmax, Ymax)` pairs, you can create a valid Polygon as follows:
   `input_polygon = Polygon.from_bbox((Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax))`
2. We should consider 2 possibilities for our data (`MyCords`) in conjunction with the `input_polygon` (follows the same pattern presented in this answer [filter by polygon draw in geodjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963437/filter-by-polygon-draw-in-geodjango/61079381#61079381)):

   1. The `input_polygon` [`intersects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#intersects) our data.

      Then the query should look like this:

      ```
      MyCords.objects.filter(geom__intersects=input_polygon)
      ```
   2. The data are completely [`within`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within) the `input_polygon`.

      Then the query should look like this:

      ```
      MyCords.objects.filter(geom__within=input_polygon)
      ```

   We can even combine the 2 and search for data that are either `within` **or** `intersect` the given `input_polygon`. To achieve that we can use Django's [`Q() object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and the `| (OR)` operator as follows:

   ```
   MyCords.objects.filter(
       Q(geom__intersects=input_polygon) |
       Q(geom__within=input_polygon)
   )
   ```